# Generate series of quarters in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I need to generate series of quarters, given start date and end date. I know of `generate_series()`, but it just does not work with `quarter`:

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series('2008-01-01 00:00'::timestamp,'2009-01-01 12:00', '1 quarter');
```

What makes quarter so special? Otherwise `generate_series()` works with pretty much everything, from microseconds to millenium:

```
select * from generate_series('2008-01-01 00:00'::timestamp,'2008-01-01 00:00:00.001', '1 microsecond');
select * from generate_series('2008-01-01 00:00'::timestamp,'2008-01-01 00:01', '1 second');
select * from generate_series('2008-01-01 00:00'::timestamp,'2008-01-01 01:00', '1 minute');
select * from generate_series('2008-01-01 00:00'::timestamp,'2008-01-01 12:00', '1 hour');
select * from generate_series('2008-01-01 00:00'::timestamp,'2009-01-01 12:00', '1 day');
select * from generate_series('2008-01-01 00:00'::timestamp,'2009-01-01 12:00', '1 week');
select * from generate_series('2008-01-01 00:00'::timestamp,'2009-01-01 12:00', '1 month');
select * from generate_series('2008-01-01 00:00'::timestamp,'2009-01-01 12:00', '1 year');
select * from generate_series('2008-01-01 00:00'::timestamp,'2009-01-01 12:00', '1 decade');
select * from generate_series('2008-01-01 00:00'::timestamp,'2009-01-01 12:00', '1 century');
select * from generate_series('2008-01-01 00:00'::timestamp,'2009-01-01 12:00', '1 millennium');
```

If `quarter` cannot be used then what is the best other option? For now, I have:

```
select 
   date_trunc('quarter',generate_series) gs 
from 
   generate_series('2008-01-01 00:00'::timestamp,'2009-01-01 12:00', '1 month') 
group by 
   gs
order by
   gs;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Shouldn't this do what you expect:

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series('2008-01-01 00:00'::timestamp,
                              '2009-01-01 12:00', '3 months');
```

Result:

```
   generate_series   
---------------------
 2008-01-01 00:00:00
 2008-04-01 00:00:00
 2008-07-01 00:00:00
 2008-10-01 00:00:00
 2009-01-01 00:00:00
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Realizing this is an old answer, but I recently ran into this. 
Adding date_trunc('quarter', your_date) to your start date will guarantee you start with the beginning of a quarter.
`SELECT * FROM generate_series(date_trunc('quarter', '2008-02-01 00:00'),
                              '2009-01-01 12:00', '3 months');`